# angular form submit is this correct way?

Tags: javascript, angular

I am using the below functions to save my form.
.ts file

```
  saveScheduleCheckin(addcheckinform: NgForm) {
    this.scheduleCheckInService.saveScheduleCheckIn(this.checkin).subscribe(data => {
      this.alertService.success('success');
      addcheckinform.reset();
    },
      error => {
        this.errorMsg = error.statusText;
      });
  }
```

Service file

```
  saveScheduleCheckIn(checkin: Object): Observable<any> {
    console.log(checkin);
    return this.http.post(`${this.url}`, checkin).pipe(catchError(this.errorHandler));
  }
```

currently, this is working and I console the data. check below image
[image]

What is that 'prototype' object (marked blue color)? is it error? this form submission is wrong?
please help me

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does JavaScript .prototype work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/572897/how-does-javascript-prototype-work)

Answer (score 0):

Everything looking fine. as per this you have created & declared

`checkin` variable as a CheckInModel model right

`public checkin: CheckInModel;`

Like above. so when you passing it to service it's printing model name as prototype

Comment: checkin variable as a CheckInModel model right  - Yes

Comment: Ok if you use any pre-defined type like (any, string, number, boolean) like that. 
The console will display appropriate prototype definition. 

Your submission is fine.